# How to extract specific elements from the Google Geocoding json response through a URL?

Tags: json, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder

So I want to be able to run this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&result_type=street_address

which returns a json response with many results...

Id like to be able to parse the json from the url itself...

so something like. .... 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&result_type=street_address&results[0].formatted_address

so that instead of getting a multiline response - I just get what I need in a single line such as...

**277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA**

Sure I can write a script to do this but I wonder if specific fields of the JSON are restful.

Am i talking smack or is this possible ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although RESTful web services may utilize JSON, the fields of JSON results themselves are not RESTful. Parsing values from the URL would probably require you to change how Google handles url processing on the server end. You'll have to get that information programmatically.

Comment: Thanks not_a_bot - so what if I wanted to get a response containing just street address based on a URL containing lat/longs .... any service that does that ?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's probably easier to just parse the response than to try to figure out a way to get it from the URL.